# Flutter Socket:How to get async resut in when i use socket.listen() many times in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Why can't I get results of listen2? How do I modify it？In the sample，I can only access the listen1 results but not the listen2 results。i am new

```
sample code:

  Future<List<int>> getResult() async {
    var a =  creatDataToken();
    var e=  await Socket.connect(MyApp.host, MyApp.port).then((Socket socket) async{
        socket.add(a);
        socket.listen((List<int> listen1) async{
          debugPrint('result listen1 :$listen1');
          List<int> loginList=  creatDataLogin(listen1);
          await  Socket.connect(MyApp.host, MyApp.port).then((Socket socket) async {
                    socket.add(loginList);
                    debugPrint('add:$loginList');
                    await socket.listen((List<int> listen2) {
                      debugPrint('result listen2 :$listen2');
                        return listen2;
                    });
              });
        });
    });
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kb9bY.png)

Comment: the debugprint  'result listen1' and  'add'  are normal print ,but the 'result listen2' is not print.

Comment: If you are already connected why connect again?

Comment: because  if  i  take out  the second  'Socket.connect...then() async',it will throw a Exception    that ' Unhandled Exception: Bad state: Stream has already been listened to' .

Comment: Why `socket.listen` twice? Why not make use of the first `socket.listen`?

Comment: i have resolved the problem ,thanks.

Comment: but there is another question that when i input the wrong username and passowrd,it print ‘---catchError--Unsupported operation: Cannot send errors on sockets’,Even if I re-enter the correct account and password

Comment: Maybe you can ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

```
 bool flag;
  Future getResult() async {
    flag = false;
   var a =  creatDataToken() ;
   var b= await Socket.connect(MyApp.host, MyApp.port).then((Socket socket){
          mSocket=socket;
          mSocket.add(a);
          mSocket.addError((e){debugPrint('---addError--$e');});
          mSocket.listen(onReceiver);
    }).catchError((error){
             debugPrint('---catchError--$error');
              ToastUtils.showShortToast('username or password error!');
              return;
           });
    return b;
  }

  void onReceiver(List<int> event) {
    if(!flag){
      debugPrint('result listen1 :$event');
      flag=true;
      List<int> loginList=  creatDataLogin(event);
      debugPrint('loginList:$loginList');
      mSocket.add(loginList);
    }else{
      debugPrint('result listen2 :$event');
      resolveResult(event);
    }
  }
```